# Conditionally Commenting with OpenXLSX

Tags: r, openxlsx

I would like to add a comment on a cell only if certain conditions are met (the cell isn't empty and a different column contains specific text) using OpenXLSX in R. Not sure if this is possible.

I can, of course, conditionally apply a style based on these conditions:

```
Name<- c("Bob", "Fred", "Smith", "Henry", "Joe")
Other<- 1:5
df<- data.frame(Name, Other)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Names")
writeData(wb, 1, df, startRow = 1, startCol=1, colNames = F)


West<- createStyle(bgFill = "#DCE6F1")
conditionalFormatting(wb, 1, cols = 2, rows = 1:5, rule = 'AND($A1 == "Smith", $B1<>"")', style = West)
```

But, as expected, trying to use this in combination with `writeComment` just returns an error that style must be a Style object:

```
conditionalFormatting(wb, 1, col = 2, rows = 1:5, rule = 'AND($A1 == "Smith", $B1<>"")', style = writeComment(wb, 1, col = "B", row = which(df$Name == "Smith"), comment = createComment(comment = "Test Comment")))
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by determining the rows which qualify for a comment `com_row` outside openxlsx function; then use `com_row` within the `writeComment` function.

```r
library(openxlsx)

Name<- c("Bob", "Fred", "Smith", "Henry", "Joe")
Other<- 1:5
df<- data.frame(Name, Other)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Names")
writeData(wb, 1, df, startRow = 1, startCol=1, colNames = F)


West<- createStyle(bgFill = "#DCE6F1")
conditionalFormatting(wb, 1, cols = 2, rows = 1:5, rule = 'AND($A1 == "Smith", $B1<>"")', style = West)

com1 <- createComment(comment = "Test Comment")
com_row <- which(df$Name == "Smith" & df$Other != "")

# wrap `writeComment` function in an if statement to deal with case 
# where there are no names = "Smith" and NAs in Other. This does away
# with the case where `which` evaluates to `integer(0)` when there
# are no elements which are indexed.

if(length(com_row) > 0){
  
  writeComment(wb, 1, col = 2, row = com_row, comment = com1)
  
}


saveWorkbook(wb, file = "condition_and_comment_eg.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Which results in:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

*Test data frame*

For case when no rows satisfy the conditions.

```
Name<- c("Bob", "Fred", "Noname", "Henry", "Joe")
Other<- c(1:2, NA_real_, 4:5)
```

Workbook output for data frame with no row meeting conditions:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, this breaks the excel file if the condition isn't met (If Smith's Other column was NA) , and when Microsoft tries to repair I lose all my comments. Secondarily,  this wouldn't then automatically remove the comment if the cell is emptied within the outputted excel file (this issue I could live with if the file didn't break).

Comment: OK, would a better test data frame have row 1 inputs of: `c("Smith", NA_real_)` And ideally you would like the comment to be conditional. This is not something I am familiar with in Excel - can you create conditional comments in Excel? I'll look into the approach for `Other` with  a value of `NA` and update the answer.

Comment: @Laura, I've just tried with row 1 as `c("Smith", NA_real_)` and the workbook generates fine for me as expected. Could you update the question to include a row with the case that fails for you?

Comment: A quick search on the internet suggests that conditional comments in Excel require a macro or VBA . See for example: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/can-excel-create-a-conditional-comment-on-a-cell.2949609/

Comment: it fails if there's no cases, so where the which function output is NA (so if row 3 has NA instead of "3" and Smith appears nowhere else in the dataset). In my case, I will only have 1 occurrence of each last name

Comment: One approach would be to wrap the `writeComment` function in an if clause. See modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is similar to Peters, just using `openxlsx2` and not using conditional formatting.

```r
library(openxlsx2)
Name <- c("Bob", "Fred", "Smith", "Henry", "Joe", "Smith", "Joe", "Smith")
Other <- c(1:5, NA, 7:8)
df <- data.frame(Name, Other)

# prepare the workbook
wb <- wb_workbook()$add_worksheet()$add_data(x = df, na.strings = NULL)

# get the required cell information
data <- wb_data(wb)
rows <- rownames(data[data$Name == "Smith" & !is.na(data$Other) & data$Other != "",])

for (row in rows) {
  
  dim <- attr(data, "dims")[row, "B"]
  c1 <- create_comment("this is a comment", "")
  
  wb$add_fill(dims = dim, color = wb_color("yellow"))
  wb$add_comment(dims = dim, comment = c1)
  
}

if (interactive()) wb$open()
```